# solr admin gives 404 errors after integrating nutch

Tags: solr, jetty, nutch

I've followed the instructions from http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/

Had solr up and running before that, could handle test cases, access admin pages, etc.

Copied the nutch schema.xml over to solr as per instructions. Worked, could access admin.

When I added in the requesthandler snippet (see 5d on the website) in solrconfig.xml going to the admin page suddenly tossed off "HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path RequestURI=/solr/admin/index.jsp"

I can't see what in the requesthandler snippet could be causing the admin to fail. Using the feb. 26 build of solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , right is:

<bool name="hl">true</bool> not <bool hl="true"/>
that works